# permission denied in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nestjs

Trying to build my dockerfile, and getting a permission denied error.
The project is a nest.js server. Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install   <<< this fails
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

and the error (on npm install) is:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:220
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:994:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
```

Any idea?

Comment: i wouldn't put stuff in the `/usr/*` volume?

Comment: Thanks. changed the WORKDIR to  /home/node or just /app,  and the error is the same. any other suggestion?

Comment: To the person who gave me the answer starting with RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown....   and then deleted his answer...  you solution worked, thank you!   My docker installation was bad. after re-installing docker your solution worked.

Comment: did you had installed the dependencies with 'npm' too?
I had the same issue, i'd installed node_modules with 'yarn install' and my dockerfile says 'npm install', so i changed my dockerfile and it works.

Comment: thanks @Dr.G, that problem has been already solved, see below. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Solved. the solution was in 2 steps:

1. re-install docker.
2. changing owner to node, like this:

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package.json .
USER node
RUN npm install
...
```

Comment: WIthout re-installing docker, you could simply use `COPY --chown node:node` (source: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1262#issuecomment-677577653).